# JCarousel scrolling forever despite no more items

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

If I have static content for my JCarousel like this:

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
    <li><img src="image1.bmp" alt="" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
    ...
    <li><img src="image6.bmp" alt="" width="75" height="75" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

then the carousel scrolls the 6 images.

If I have an empty list:

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
</ul>
```

and load the items dynamically:

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    itemLoadCallback: myCarouselItemLoadCallback,
});

function myCarouselItemLoadCallback(carousel, state)
{
    if (state === "init")
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < dummyData.length; ++i)
        {
            carousel.add(i, dummyData[i].ihtml);
        }
    }
}
```

where dummyData is defined as:

```
var dummyData =
[
    {
        ihtml: "<li><img src='image1.bmp' alt='' width='75' height='75'/></li>"
    },
    etc for the other 5 items
];
```

then I get the carousel with the 6 items, but the Next button does not disable after the 6 are exhausted, instead I can hit Next forever, and it just keeps showing 3 more 'images' - all of which are just placeholders (don't know what to call it, just an empty box where there would be an image).

So my question is why doesn't the carousel stop at 6 like it did with the static content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly it seems you need to explicitly set the size...

```
carousel.options.size = dummyData.length;
```